# Form action with url and javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to link to a form on a different webpage, but I also would like to submit that same form, with the data in my own form.

The form I try to link to and submit has a Javascript action. Is there any way I can link my submit button to that page, and also execute the javascript action on that page?

This is the form I would like to "link"/submit to:

```
<form action="javascript:checkUser()" method="post">
```

This is my small form:

```
<form action="http://linkto.thefo.rm/check/" method="POST" target="framestart">
<input class="field" id="gegevens" type="text" size="23" name="gegevens" value=""/>                                 
<input onclick="javascript: svtabs.expandit(0);" type="submit"  value="Zoeken"/>
</form>
```

As you can see I already use an onclick function. I thought just adding the checkUser() function from the other page would work.. but it doesn't.

Changing the form action to the url followed by checkUser() doesn't work either.

What is the correct way to link to a form and submitting that same form so it executes the javascript funtion checkUser()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `action` you have to use `onsubmit`, as this is going to be an event of the `form`.

```
<form onsubmit="checkUser(); return false;" method="post">
```

Use the above method if you are doing everything by AJAX - sending of data to the server and stuff.

In case, you are handling the next steps in the `checkUser()` and finally submitting the form in a traditional method, use:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkUser();" method="post">
```

In the above method, you need to `return false` if the validation fails and `true` if it succeeds and you are happy to send the form.

Comment: thnx for the quick response. But since I am calling the checkUser() on a form on another page, how do I specify the url for the form with the checkUser funtion on it?

onsubmit="action='http://linkto.thefo.rm/check/'; return checkUser();" 

something like that?

Comment: @PeterBuring You can't do that.

Comment: i was afraid that it wouldn't be possible.. thanks for the reply